# TypeError: Cannot read property 'slideTo' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ion-slides

I am using `ion-Slides` to show the selected image from the gallery and swipe them horizontally and it is working good but I want to show the last selected image on the screen.

I tried using `slideTo()` and it causing the type error.

For more clarity:  I am running a loop where I push selected images from gallery in with `base64` conversion into an `array` and pass it in an `image` tag to show images on the HTML screen.

any help would be great.

Comment: mind adding your html and slideTo() implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

`@ViewChild('slides', { static: false }) slider: IonSlides;`
I faced a similar problem.
Had to change static from true to false.

Comment: Well I had to set it to true. No idea y

Comment: @vigamage I don't have a clue too as I don't work much with ionic anymore. Glad it worked for you. Happy coding mate!

Comment: I had to set it to false. No clue why but this was a life saviour. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionSlidesDidLoad` event to make sure ion-slide has loaded.

subscribe for the event in your html file like following sample:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides  (ionSlidesDidLoad)="slidesLoaded($event)">
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

and in your ts file add the following method:

```
    public slidesLoaded($event) {
    //move to slide number 2
    $event.target.slideTo(2);
    }
```

This event is available in Ionic 4 and later.